# Why did the behavior of my jsp submit button change?

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

We've recently come across a bug in our code - a page with two submit buttons, one of which adds a new row of form fields to submit, and another that submits the entered data.

Recently, the button that submits data has been adding new rows instead.

```
<html:submit value="Add New Range" styleClass="button" property="<%=relevantActionForm.ACTION_NEW_DATE%>" />*

*public static final String ACTION_NEW_DATE = "anotherDate";

<html:submit value="Submit" styleClass="button" />&nbsp
<html:cancel styleClass="button" />
```

These are the buttons that appear in the JSP page, but the page itself (as in, all the code for this jsp page including these buttons) hasn't changed in over a year.  Oddly, when testing this problem, the 'cancel' button works fine, and can even execute the action properly if we comment out the code to handle a cancellation.

We've pinned down the last working version, and have rolled back every possible class that could affect this page.

The jsp page, our struts config file, our tile-defs, the action class, the form class, the page it forwards to, even our security XML.

None of this has had any effect.

We are truly running out of options, and looking for more - what possible reason could there be for the behavior of the page to change so radically, when none of the obvious classes seem to have any impact on the change in function?

Comment: You know your code better than we do. If you don't provide code for the buttons, we can't help you.

Comment: @Zircon added, though the jsp code itself hasn't changed in over a year according to our source control.  Oddly enough, the cancel button still works, and can even load the action if we remove the code to handle cancellation.  I've added that info to my question as well.

Comment: Look at the generated source and do some console.log lines in your view and some output lines in your controller to see what the buttons are doing.

Comment: @ManoDestra It doesn't even seem to enter the controller it's supposed to, if any.  And it directs right back to the same page with a new row of data to enter.  While the other 'submit' button does the exact same thing.

Comment: Are both of those submits inside the same form element? They shouldn't be, unless you have some logic that amends the action appropriately to direct you to the appropriate controller. You could probably just do the new row part on the client side without the submission. And leave the submission of the form to a single button.

Comment: @ManoDestra That would be ideal... unfortunately at this point, since this is all legacy code, that would mean re-creating that functionality from scratch. It DOES seem like it would work through, so I'll consider that as a nuclear option.

Comment: Also, I'd check it on multiple browsers to see if the same behavior is replicated, or if it's browser specific.

Comment: @ManoDestra Chrome doesn't seem to behave any differently, though even if it did, we're required to be IE compatible.

Comment: IE is abominable and a waste of developer effort. My condolences :-p